# JBoss 5.1 removing whitespaces in response html

Tags: html, jsp, web-applications, optimization, jboss

Is there any JBoss 5.1 plugin or utility that automatically removed all the leading and trailing white spaces in an HTML it is sending as a response. Or something similar can be done to JSP when they are deployed.
Even an application specific setting would do.

I am already using

```
<init-param>
 <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
 <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

but this is not working for me.

I have read other articles which says to reduce the file before deploying it, but I was wondering if there is any automated solution to this, instead of cleaning each file manually.

Comment: You need to distinguish between whitespace left by taglibs/scriptlets and the whitespace which you've embedded yourself. The mentioned init param only removes the first category of whitespace. So, what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: Thanks. I see now, I thought it would do both. I am actually looking to remove both types of whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [ServletFilter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) to do this.

For example code doing pretty much what you're after, look at this [whitespace filter](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/whitespacefilter.html) on BalusC's blog.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was assuming this to be a common problem and JBoss would have had some inbuilt mechanism to handle that. Am I wrong thinking that?

Comment: I don't know of anything built into JBoss.